# Highcharts: Polar columns datalabels inside position

Tags: formatting, position, highcharts, pie-chart

I'm trying to get values (datalabels) of a columns polar chart INSIDE the actual column, and not on top of it. I've set `inside: true` property but it does not seem to have any effect, although it works pretty nicely while using a regular stacked columns chart for example.

Here is the fiddle showing the issue: http://jsfiddle.net/deurk/BeVyt/2/

Ideally, I'd like to have the datalabels in their "shares" if there is enough space, with white color. Does anyone have a workaround for this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Indeed it looks like a bug, so I've reported it here https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/1688